# makeCluster fails with remote server Ubuntu

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I have a cluster running Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS and R 4.3.3.  I am trying to use clusterApply with a simple network of workstations.  When I call parallel::makecluster with an array of serveripaddresses, R just waits unless the serveripaddreseses all refer to the localhost.   I tried allowing all traffic in and out from ports 22 and 11000 to 11999, and still have the same issue.

```
# Define the cluster
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(c(server1,server2,server3))
# Distribute the computation across the cluster
results <- parallel::clusterApply(cl, c(1, 2, 3), function(x) {
    x^2
})
# Close the cluster when done
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
# Results will contain the output of the computations performed on each server
print(results)
```

I also tried the following

```
workers <- c(rep(server1,2), rep(server,2))
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(workers, outfile = "")
```

I got back the following:
starting worker pid=2517175 on machinename:11168 at 22:30:24.300
Error in socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  :
cannot open the connection
Calls:  -> workLoop -> makeSOCKmaster
In addition: There were 17 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Execution halted

The following seems to work:
workers <- c(server_1, server_2)
cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(workers, revtunnel = TRUE,        outfile = "", verbose = TRUE)
results <- parallel::clusterApply(cl, c(1, 2, 3), function(x) {
x^2
})
parallel::stopCluster(cl)

```
print(results)
```

Does that mean IT is blocking traffic?  RStudio is asking me for a password for every worker on localhost if called by ipaddress, and some servers.  Is there an easy way to provide it in the code and not be prompted repeatedly?  I likely want to run multiple processes on multiple nodes.

I am actually getting worse performance with the cluster than with a single server because I see far fewer R processes running on localhost than I specified, and am able to use with mcmapply.  Any ideas why?  I am assuming this is atypical because it defeats the purpose of using a cluster.

Comment: What does `parallel:::getClusterOption("type")` return?

Comment: It returns PSOCK